# Kendo UI - k-scheduler-update - k-scheduler-cancel - button color on activation

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I've looked high and low for the answer to this, but I've yet to find the answer, so I decided to ask my first stackoverflow question.

I'm working with Kendo UI, and it has built in functionality to change say a k-button on activation (k-button:active) however I have a few buttons that aren't only k-buttons, they are k-scheduler-update and k-scheduler-cancel. The issue is I need to remove the "orange-on-click" from all buttons across my project. The k-buttons were easy enough; the scheduler-update and scheduler-cancel are not as easy. I don't know if there is something built in such as the :active (that specifically didn't work) that I don't know of, but I haven't been able to find it, either.

In addition, I have two other locations that have k-buttons that are object other than k-buttons as well; they are .k-multiselect-wrap li. Their coloring is fine except when in Chrome if you click-hold and drag the button away, the original button turns orange and stays orange until you let go. That needs to go away as well, and I am having a difficult time with that, also.

I'm not sure what other specifics are needed; I'm working with Kendo UI, jquery, javascript, java, and jsp. Thanks for any help offered.

Edit:

This was copied/pasted from another css to the relevant css.

```
.k-secondary .k-button:active
{
    border-color:#e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #505050;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this was found online and added to the other relevant css.

```
.k-multiselect-wrap li 
{
margin: 1px 0 1px 1px;
padding: .1em .15em .1em .4em;
line-height: 1.5em;
float: left;
border-color:#e6e6e6;
box-shadow: none;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
color: black;
text-shadow: none;
text-decoration: none;

}
```

Edit:

Just an FYI; I was not able to find a way to edit these css settings. I am however implementing a workaround in the project; I just wanted to let anyone who reads this know. I am changing the Kendo UI template to erase any instance of the color orange, which does have the caveat of adding other small style changes, but at this time it is satisfactory.

Comment: it would help if you could share the (successful) changes you've made so far, and maybe a screenshot to illustrate or (better) a demo; in general, you should probably look for classes like .k-state-active and .k-state-hover

Comment: Sure, I'll throw the successful changes up, but honestly I think it's pretty basic css stuff; I mean it was new to me, but I didn't initially include it because once I saw what was needed it seemed like it was a pretty basic step.

Comment: Also I attempted to override the .k-state-active and .k-state-hover in the same areas and it did not change the scheduler-update and scheduler-cancel active colors.